# Connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine is slower than from localhost

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

So I've been trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL from my Google App Engine. Everything works, but the latency is very high. A simple select query is taking about 1.3 seconds. However, when I connect from localhost, it takes a much shorter time. The difference in connection is the following:

in App Engine yaml

```
MYSQL_DSN: /cloudsql/instanceName
MYSQL_USER: user
MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
```

in App Engine php

```php
$servername = getenv('MYSQL_DSN');
$username = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
$password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
$dbname = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE');
$connection = new mysqli(null, $username, $password, $dbname, null, $servername);
```

when connecting to Cloud SQL in localhost I use:

```php
$servername = "ip.address";
$username = getenv('MYSQL_USER');
$password = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');
$dbname = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE');
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

When connecting from localhost, I have authorized my computer's ip address in my Cloud SQL dashboard, so connecting directly through ip address is no problem. My problem now is that when I am running my php files from localhost to connect to Cloud SQL, the latency is lower than when connecting from App Engine. Any idea why and how I can fix this?

Comment: how are you measuring the latency?

Comment: @danCornilescu app engine dashboard shows latency, so the interesting thing is when I set allowed networks for my Cloud SQL to 0.0.0.0/0 and connect directly through Cloud SQL ip address it is much faster. This means something about App Engine connecting to Cloud SQL's security check is slowing down the connection. :/ Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this a first or second generation Cloud SQL instance?  What region is the application and/or SQL instance in?  Is the latency consistently as long or intermittent?  How in fact are you measuring the SQL instance's latency?  The App Engine dashboard can provide the latency for the application but not specifically for the Cloud SQL instance.  You could add logs in your application or use [Stackdriver Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/viewing-details) to see the latency for just the communication between application and SQL instance.

Comment: It is a second generation at asia-northeast1. Latency from App Engine was about 1300ms and I measured specifically the $connection = new mysqli() part was taking the longest. Which was like 1000ms when using socket connection. It seems like it has something to do with the location of the instances. Some Google Cloud Support people are taking a look at this issue for me over at App Engine Groups!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue affecting Cloud SQL instances in the **asia-northeast1** region.  It is tracked on the **Cloud SQL public issue tracker** under [Issue 197](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=197).  Please star the issue to support it getting appropriate attention.

The underlying issue relates to scaling up the Japan (asia-northeast1) operation which just launched in 2016.  There does not seem to be an ideal workaround at the moment.  My only recommendation would be to try moving the Cloud SQL instance outside of asia-northeast1.  You may be able to reduce the latency using asia-east1 (Taiwan) or a closer region still if that move is feasible in your situation.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and just switched to asia-east1 with your advice. The latency is however still very slow unfortunately. I may need to think about using AWS RDS until google solves this issue.

Comment: I assume using a non Asia location is infeasible?

Comment: You could also deploy your application to the flexible environment and MySQL on a Compute Engine instance in the same network.  That should allow communication using internal IPs.  I'm not entirely sure if this effectively reduces latency to a significant degree as I've not tested this myself.